# Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to..." when trying to pass the first DataRow of a table

Tags: c#, datarow

I have a DataSet created in VS 2017 DS designer and I am trying to retrieve the first row returned from the DataAdapter. When I  try to pass the first row `([TblEventTypes.Rows[0])` in TypesRow I get the error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to
> 'DSEventTypes.EventTypesRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
> missing a cast)?"

Here is the code I have:

```cs
private DSEventTypesTableAdapters.EventTypesTableAdapter _EventTypesDataAdapter;
protected DSEventTypesTableAdapters.EventTypesTableAdapter EventTypesAdapter
{
    get
    {
        if (_EventTypesDataAdapter == null)
        {
            _EventTypesDataAdapter = new DSEventTypesTableAdapters.EventTypesTableAdapter();
        }
        return _EventTypesDataAdapter;
    }
}
public bool GetEventTypeByID(int EventTypeID, ref string EventType, ref string Results)
{
    DSEventTypes.EventTypesRow TypesRow;
    DSEventTypes.EventTypesDataTable TblEventTypes = EventTypesAdapter.GetDataById(EventTypeID);
    if (TblEventTypes.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        TypesRow = TblEventTypes.Rows[0];
    }
    return true;
}
```

The error appears in the line `TypesRow = TblEventTypes.Rows[0];` and the red error line appears under `TblEventTypes.Rows[0];`. The declaration of "TypesRow" is correct as the VS 2017 intellisense does list all the column names in the table.

I am new to C# (years ago used C++) and for many years I have been creating my Windows and Web applications is VB.NET so I am probably missing something simple and I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages :( _"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'DSEventTypes.EventTypesRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?"_ means that you can't implicitly convert a variable of type `System.Data.DataRow` to `DSEventTypes.EventTypesRow`, but there is an explicit conversion. Are you missing a cast operator?

Comment: Sorry Vasily, as I said, I am new to C# and did not know the way to cast it.

Comment: @JohnV it's ok to be novice, but you really should read exception messages carefully. They are almost always (literally) contains a solution to your problem. If you only looked for _"C# cast"_ with google, you would immediately find [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) at docs and so there would be no reason to ask this question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
TypesRow = (EventTypesRow)(tblEventTypes.Rows[0]);
```

Comment: Why should one try that? Please add an explanation to your code such that others can learn from it